# calculating cos x n steps deep in racket

Tags: math, racket

I wondered if what I wrote is correct; it's a project for school so I'd like to be sure it gives the correct output before I upload it.

The mathematical algorithm for calculating cos x = 1 - ((x^2)/(2!)) + ((x^4)/(4!)) - ((x^6)/(6!)) + ...

So here's my code:

```lisp
(define (calc-cos x n)
  (define (hulp ctr res prevPow prevFac switch)
    (let ((switchOp (if (eq? (modulo switch 2) 0) + -)))
      (if (> ctr (+ 2 n))
          res
          (let ((newPow (* prevPow x x))
                (newFac (* (- ctr 1) ctr prevFac)))
            (hulp (+ ctr 2) (switchOp res (/ newPow newFac)) newPow newFac (+ switch 1))))))
  (hulp 2 1 1 1 1))
```

Comment: Have you tried putting in input and seeing if the correct output comes out?

Comment: ofcouyrse i tried inputting things, the problem is I do ot have anything to compare my output to...

Comment: Take your pocket calculator, or any scripting language which can compute a cosine.

Comment: did that also, used python, and the output is correct, but as since my time is not infinite I cannot check every single input for a correct otput, I'd really like a theoretical proof if possible...

Comment: You can argue that the **partial sum** computed by the computer matches that of the mathematics.  That is, given n, prove that the computation computes the correct partial sum.

Answer (score 1):

Let us more precisely define what we're trying to compute here.  We have the infinite sum:

```
1 - ((x^2)/(2!)) + ((x^4)/(4!)) - ((x^6)/(6!)) + ...
```

Realize that the "..." here is informal notation for "process keeps going on forever".  It is not a formal notation: it's asking the reader to think what the pattern is.  Let us formally express what the terms of the sum should be.

Let T_n be the nth term:

```
T_n = (-1)^n * x^(2n)/(2n)!
```

Do you accept that this is a formal representation of the nth term of the partial sum?

If so, we can express this in terms of our programming language:

```
(define (t_n x n)
  (/ (* (expt -1 n) 
        (expt x (* 2 n)))
     (fact (* 2 n))))

(define (fact n)
  (if (= n 0)
      1
      (* n (fact (sub1 n)))))
```

I do not know if what t_n computes is what your function computes.  I do think that the t_n function here is an accurate representation of the math function.

If you accept that t_n computes the nth term of the partial sum, then:

```
(define (cos/approx x)
  (for/sum ([k (in-range 100)])
    (t_n x k)))
```

should be acceptable to you as an approximation of the cosine.

Once we start from a definition of cos/approx that is correct, we can start to work to make it efficient, via step-by-step rewriting to do things like preserve the accumulated factorials, etc., to eventually reach your definition.  I believe there is a path to do so, though it may not fit in the margins of this textarea.  :)